# Google reCaptcha to work in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I'm getting so close... loading the element in is fine EXCEPT for the fact that something in the way the reCaptcha script works makes it so that rendering isn't done when you create an instance of the 'g-recaptcha' class. SO. The reCaptcha WILL load (every time/functionally correct) if I use...

```
// the div that contains the reCaptcha is in < Contact / >
ReactDOM.render( < Contact / > , document.getElementById('non-header'));

// adding another recaptcha/api.js to the head
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

This is clearly a horrendous solution as every time 'Contact' is loaded another script is appended to the head. Not only that... there's already a reCaptcha script I put in the head in the initial document (this is just re-instigating it over and over). Using the libraries API and resetting the reCaptcha doesn't work (see below)...

```
ReactDOM.render( < Contact / > , document.getElementById('non-header'));

//var imported = document.createElement('script');
//imported.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
//document.head.appendChild(imported);

grecaptcha.reset();


74:2  error  'grecaptcha' is not defined  no-undef !!!
```

So somehow I need to access the script methods for the reCaptcha div within React. Contact.js is an incredibly basic React component. It may as well just be...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/Contact.css';

class Contact extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='g-recaptcha' id='recaptcha' data-sitekey='******************************'></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Maybe even just getting an idea of the proper way to include 3rd party scripts in a React Component would help a lot if anyone can provide me some guidance.

Does this seem to be on the right trail (link: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/using-external-script-libraries/2256)?

Comment: Not sure if this helps you out, but this component works out of the box: https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha

Comment: I was looking to use a GitHub project as an option, I've seen some good ones and got it working with: https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha

I think I'd prefer to get it working without though. I'm trying to learn React so I'm going to need to understand importing libraries eventually (or is that not a primary function of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha

This library works fine. Here's the usage:

```
<Recaptcha sitekey="" 
    render="explicit" 
    hl={"ja"} 
    onloadCallback={} 
    verifyCallback={*} />
```

Comment: And how do you verify a callback then if in param you need to pass secret key?

Comment: if you want a secure site you must hold only public key on frontend. you must use your secret key on backend. when you use this liblary this will generate a key for you you will send this key witj your form attributes and you will do a request for google with your secret key and your generated key. google will response with success or not for you

Comment: an example request  :  https ://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={your_secret_key}&response={generated_key}"&remoteip=192.168.1.234

Comment: @VahapGençdal Can't it be a security issue when secret keys are used in the URL? I.e. they could be placed in log files and stored in other ways on the system.

Comment: the query I used with secret key used in the backend, its using send verification code to google and it is not unsecure

Comment: This is not the correct answer and don't have to be, we need solution to the actual problem not a link to a library!!!